# How to load table data from cloud sql (MYSQL Instance) to Hive in cloud datproc?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to load table data from cloud sql (MYSQL Instance) to Hive in cloud datproc in GCP.

i came to know, i can do it by using below methods.

1. using sqoop job. - there is no much documentation on this. any sample query how to use it will be helpful for me.
2. using cloudsql connector take the data from cloudsql and save as CSV in GCS and load those csv files into HIVE table.

please let me know if my 2nd method is a good practice or not? let me know if there are any other ways to do this task please..

Comment: Both should work, if you are not familiar with Sqoop, just go with the 2nd.

Comment: sqoop is pretty much standard when you extract from RDBMS. You can tune it/use incremental. Always better to use standard tool.